# Android user preference fragment not displaying

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to establish a settings screen for my Android 4.0+ app. I can not get the two checkboxes `vibratePreference` and `soundPreference` to display. I don't think `UserPreferencesFragment` ever instantiates.  Below are the files involved. I've been on this for a couple of nights and I can not figure out what I'm missing. What am I over looking?

Thanks, PLA

preferences_headers.xml

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <header
        android:fragment="com.hometelco.hfa.activities.UserPreferencesFragment"
        android:summary="Home Field Advantage user settings"
        android:title="User Settings" />

</preference-headers>
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="User Settings" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="vibratePreference"
            android:summary="Vibrate on adds and updates"
            android:title="Vibrate" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="soundPreference"
            android:summary="Play sound on adds and updates"
            android:title="Sound" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

UserPreferencesActivity.java

```
package com.hometelco.hfa.activities;

import java.util.List;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.hometelco.hfa.R;

public class UserPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "UserPreferencesActivity";

    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBuildHeaders before load");
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
        Log.i(TAG, "onBuildHeaders after load");
    }
}
```

UserPreferencesFragment.java

```
package com.hometelco.hfa.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.hometelco.hfa.R;

public class UserPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    private final static String TAG = "UserPreferencesFragment";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "UserPreferencesFragment onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should have both a preference activity and a preference fragment.

Comment: From what I've gathered you load the preference headers in the activity. The preference headers point to the fragment(s). You can have multiple fragments. I am basing that assumption from the book "Professional Android 4 Application Development". See chapter 7 code here: http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/74/11181022/DOWNLOAD/9781118102275%20PA4AD.zip

Comment: What do you see when you run this code?  What does the logcat say?

Comment: Here is the logcat. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_WwphlQixTbMW5LRXEyRUJNazg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologize. My code was actually working the entire time. I was just not pressing on the settings header. When I did my check-boxes appeared. This is not what I want so I changed `PreferenceActivity` to the code seen below.

```
package com.hometelco.hfa.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.hometelco.hfa.R;

public class UserPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "UserPreferencesActivity";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate hasHeaders: " + hasHeaders());
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
         new UserPreferencesFragment()).commit();
    }
/*
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBuildHeaders before load");
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
        Log.i(TAG, "onBuildHeaders after load");
    }
*/
    public static class UserPreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        private final static String TAG = "UserPreferencesFragment";

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i(TAG, "fragment onCreate");
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who helped me find the error of my ways.

PLA

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the error in this line:

```
android:fragment="com.hometelco.hfa.activities.UserPreferencesFragment"
```

Looking at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), they show calling that line using a format of `packaganame.preferenceactivity$preferencefragment`...

I believe that line in preferences_headers.xml should be:

```
android:fragment="com.hometelco.hfa.activities.UserPreferencesActivity$UserPreferencesFragment"
```

Comment: Changing `android:fragment` to `android:name` in `preferences_headers.xml` did not make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, one last though.  Try `onCreateView` for your preferences fragment instead of `onCreate`.  Every other fragment I've ever used did it that way.

Comment: Changing `onCreate` to `onCreateView` did not make a difference. I never see the output from `Log.i(TAG, "UserPreferencesFragment onCreate");` in LogCat.

Comment: Note to self... if all else fails, check the documentation.  :p  I believe I have found the issue.  Check out my updated answer

Comment: That syntax is applicable if I had `UserPreferencesFragment` as an inner-class of `UserPreferencesActivity`. I did have it that way originally but after having trouble I moved the fragment out in to its own class. I have since moved it back to an inner-class of the activity and changed `preferences_headers.xml` back to `android:fragment="com.hometelco.hfa.activities.UserPreferencesActivity$UserPreferencesFragment"`. Still no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
```

rather than:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

You also need to call you check boxes like so:

```
     final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
     if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
         checkBox.setChecked(false);
     }
```

You should add ID's to you check boxes. Here is a link that might help you:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Comment: I moved preferences.xml to the layout directory and changed my code to `addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);` but it did not fix my issue. Still no check-boxes. Thanks, PLA

Comment: Edited post. Hope that helps!

Comment: Having preferences in xml folder is standard and will not cause a problem.